# What is the difference between Flask and Docker?

Tags: docker, flask, deployment, software-design

I am lost in these words. Watched a lot of videos and articles. But I am not able to understand the difference. Flask helps me to create web interface which can be used only on my local system. But what does docker do? Does it make the application visible to world with url? Requesting answer in very simple words..

Answer (score 3):

Flask is a web framework in that it provides an API for the python language with which web applications can be built, such as a website or a backend service.

Docker is a containerization tool which deals with the deployment of applications and the environment in which they run. Docker provides a lightweight alternative to Virtual Machines - a lightweight software environment in which an application can run independently, with dependencies handled by Docker. Docker environments can vary in operating system, the programming language of the application being deployed, and more.

I may, for example, build a web application in python using libraries provided by the flask API, then deploy the application on a server in a docker environment running a Windows Operating system.